# EasyAdmin3 / Symfony / Twig - url generator with route name and params in Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, easyadmin

I'm trying to generate EasyAdmin3 url inside my template with some params, but for some reason they are not present in a controller.

Twig template:

```
<a href="{{ ea_url().setRoute('route_name').set('id', 1) }}">xxx</a>

<a href="{{ ea_url({'routeName': 'route_name', 'id':1}) }}">yyy</a>

Error with missing EA context:
<a href="{{ path('route_name', {'id': 1}) }}">zzz</a>
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/something/{id}", name="rounte_name")
 */
public function xyz($id = null, Request $request, AdminContext $context)
{
    dd($_GET['id'], $request->request->all(), $context->getRequest()->request->all());
    ...
}
```

The $_GET['id'] works, but request and context are empty [].

Any idea how to generate route by name with params?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need the `ea_url()` helper function if you are just generating regular named routes in twig. You should be able to use the `path()` [twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path) provided by Symfony.

```
{{ path(route_name, route_parameters = [], relative = false) }}
```

If you are trying to create a link to an EasyAdmin controller action, then you can use the `ea_url()` helper, but you have to specify the controller and action as well. Try something like:

```
{% set url = ea_url()
                .setController('App\\Controller\\Admin\\FoobarCrudController')
                .setAction('customFooAction')
                .setEntityId(entity.instance.id)
                .set('myParam', 'baz') %}
<a href="{{ url }}">Custom Foobar Action</a>
```

Then in your controller, everything should be available as per usual via the `$context` variable...

```
public function customFooAction(AdminContext $context)
{
    $entity = $context->getEntity()->getInstance();
    $myParam = $context->getRequest()->get('myParam');
}
```

This works for me, I hope it helps.